# how to generate attention map with sparse tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, sparse-matrix

I am new to `MinkowskiEngine` and I am trying to generate an attention map. `key` should be transposed and multiply to `query`. I tried to transpose the `key` by accessing to its features and I handled the coordinates using `coordinate_manager` which should be the same as `query` according to its [document](https://nvidia.github.io/MinkowskiEngine/tutorial/sparse_tensor_basic.html). `query` size is `torch.Size([152, 16])` and `key` size is `torch.Size([16, 2])` which I expect that the multiplying should work. But actually is it not working. The error is `The size of tensor a (16) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 1` which means if the `torch.Size([x, 2])` or vice versa for key(`torch.Size([x, 16])`) it will work. What is the issue?

```
class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    """ Self attention Layer"""
    def __init__(self, in_dim):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()

        self.linear_query = ME.MinkowskiLinear(in_dim, in_dim//8)
        self.linear_key = ME.MinkowskiLinear(in_dim, in_dim//8)
        self.linear_value = ME.MinkowskiLinear(in_dim, in_dim//8)
        self.pooling = ME.MinkowskiGlobalPooling()
        self.broadcast_mul = ME.MinkowskiBroadcastMultiplication()

    def forward(self, x):
        identity = x
        a = self.linear_query(x)
        b = self.pooling(x)
        b = self.linear_key(b)
        b_feat_t = b.features.T
        bT = ME.SparseTensor(features=b_feat_t, device = a.device, coordinate_map_key=a.coordinate_map_key, coordinate_manager=a.coordinate_manager)
        print (a.size())
        print(b.size())
        print (bT.size())
        c = self.pooling(x)
        c = self.linear_value(c)
        attmap = a * bT
        attmap = attmap/self.dimension
        out = ME.MinkowskiFunctional.sigmoid(attmap)
        out = out * c
        out = out + identity
        return out
```